# How to get the destination of a certain map task output file in ReduceTask.java

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

as said in the headline, I want to retreive the location of a certain intermediate map output by the taskAttemptId.

I'm able to pull the relative destination by using the "TaskTracker.getIntermediateOutputDir()" function, but how do I get absolute path?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable "mapOutputLoc" has the information about where the data is in form of an URL.